# Application.OnKey stopped overwriting default keyboard shortcuts

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have this piece of code to make CTRL+R run my_sub:

```
Application.OnKey "^{R}", "my_sub"
```

It used to work but fine but now after running it I find that CTRL+R is still bound to its default (Fill Right).

If I change it to this

```
Application.OnKey "^+{R}", "my_sub"
```

then CTRL+SHIFT+R triggers my_sub.

But even if I try a CTRL+ one letter combo which doesn't already have a default value it still doesn't work, e.g.

```
Application.OnKey "^{Q}", "my_sub"
```

leaves CTRL+Q still doing nothing.

I can't think of anything I've changed in my set-up since when it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use  the **l.c. r**:

```
Application.OnKey "^{r}", "my_sub"
```

then the lower case **r** will be bound. That is  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>r</kbd>